# problema com condiçao de existencia no while python. turtle

Tags: python, while

Estou com dificuldade para resolver um exercício de um livro de programação.

O exercício pede para que eu crie 2 tartarugas e as movimente aleatoriamente, de tal maneira que cada tartaruga ande 50 unidades para frente, dai vire ou para a esquerda, ou para a direita, 90 graus. As tartarugas devem "nascer" num lugar aleatório dentro do espaço delimitado da tela.
Elas devem andar livremente até que elas 'se toquem'. Quando isso ocorrer, o programa deve parar. Eu consegui escrever tudo, até essa condição final.

A minha dificuldade esta la no final do código, na função `caminho_ate_parada`. minha ideia é que enquanto as coordenadas (x, y) de alex e tess forem diferentes entre si, o programa continua rodando. Caso as coordenadas (x, y) de alex forem iguais as coordenas (x, y) de tess, o programa deve parar. o estranho é que as vezes o programa para quando as duas tartarugas estão no mesmo valor do eixo (x), entretanto em diferentes valores do eixo (y).

O que posso incrementar no código pra resolver isso?

Como eu nao posso mandar mais de 2 arquivos aqui, criei um blog so pra colocar as imagens do código

[link do meu blog com as imagens](http://ficheiro-pessoal.blogspot.com.br/2016/04/blog-post.html)

```
import random
import turtle

alex = turtle.Turtle()
tess = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()

tess.shape('turtle')
tess.color('blue')
tess.speed(0)
alex.shape('arrow')
alex.color('red')
alex.speed(0)

def isInScreenAlex(w,t1):                                
    leftBound = - w.window_width()//2 + 100              
    rightBound = w.window_width()//2 - 100               
    topBound = w.window_height()//2 - 100                
    bottomBound = -w.window_height()//2 + 100            

    turtleX = t1.xcor()                                  
    turtleY = t1.ycor()                                  
    stillInAlex = True                                   
    if turtleX > rightBound or turtleX < leftBound:      
        stillInAlex = False                              
    if turtleY > topBound or turtleY < bottomBound:      
        stillInAlex = False                              
    return stillInAlex                                   


def isInScreenTess(w,t2):                                
    leftBound = - w.window_width()//2 + 100              
    rightBound = w.window_width()//2 - 100               
    topBound = w.window_height()//2 - 100                
    bottomBound = -w.window_height()//2 + 100            

    turtleX = t2.xcor()                                  
    turtleY = t2.ycor()                                   
    stillInTess = True                                   
    if turtleX > rightBound or turtleX < leftBound:      
        stillInTess = False                              
    if turtleY > topBound or turtleY < bottomBound:      
        stillInTess = False                              
    return stillInTess                                   


def compXa():                                                                              
    MaxXAxisA = int(random.randrange(- wn.window_width()//5, wn.window_width()//5 ))        
    while MaxXAxisA % 50 != 0:                                                              
        MaxXAxisA = MaxXAxisA + 1                                                           
    return MaxXAxisA                                                                        

def compYa():                                                                              
    MaxYAxisA = int(random.randrange(-wn.window_height()//5, wn.window_height()//5 ))       
    while MaxYAxisA % 50 != 0:                                                              
        MaxYAxisA = MaxYAxisA + 1                                                          
    return MaxYAxisA                                                                       

xa = int(compXa())
ya = int(compYa())

alex.penup()                                                                               
alex.goto(xa, ya)                                                                          
alex.pendown()                                                                            


def compXt():
    MaxXAxisT = int(random.randrange(- wn.window_width()//5, wn.window_width()//5))
    while MaxXAxisT % 50 != 0:
        MaxXAxisT = MaxXAxisT + 1
    return MaxXAxisT

def compYt():                                                                             
    MaxYAxisT = int(random.randrange(-wn.window_height()//5, wn.window_height()//5))
    while MaxYAxisT % 50 != 0:
        MaxYAxisT = MaxYAxisT + 1
    return MaxYAxisT

xt = int(compXt())
yt = int(compYt())

tess.penup()                                                                              
tess.goto(xt, yt)                                                           
tess.pendown()                                                                            


def positionAlex():
    if isInScreenAlex(wn, alex) == True:

        coin = random.randrange(0,2)
        if coin == 0:
            alex.left(90)
        else:                                                                            
            alex.right(90)                                                             

        alex.forward(50)

    else:
        alex.left(180)
        alex.forward(50)


def positionTess():
    if isInScreenTess(wn, tess) == True:

        coin2 = random.randrange(0,2)
        if coin2 == 0:
            tess.left(90)
        else:                                                                             
            tess.right(90)                                                                

        tess.forward(50)

    else:
        tess.left(180)
        tess.forward(50)



def caminho_ate_parada():    
    while tess.xcor() != alex.xcor() and tess.ycor() != alex.ycor():                      
        tess.xcor()                                                                       
        tess.ycor()
        alex.xcor()                         
        alex.ycor()                                                                       
        positionAlex()
        positionTess()


caminho_ate_parada()
wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Deveria ser `or`, não `and`. Você quer que o programa continue rodando enquanto as coordenadas x forem diferentes ou as coordenadas y forem diferentes, não enquanto as coordenadas x e coordenadas y forem diferentes.

Comment: mas as coordenadas `x` de tess e alex devem ser iguais `and` as coordenadas `y` também. 
eu quero que as 2 expreçoes sejam falsas para que o programa pare. ja que é um par de coordenadas e os valores de `x` devem ser iguais entre si, e os valores de `y` devem ser iguais entre si.

eu testei com o `or` e nao funcionou.

eu acho que o problema esta em definir o valor de cada coordenada para cada interação separada. já que cada movimento gera uma nova coordenada e essa nova coordenada precisa ser avaliada

Answer (score 0):

O programa está parando porquê a condição do seu `while` requer que duas expressões sejam verdadeiras para que o programa continue. Isso é, o `while` rodará enquanto `x1` for diferente de `x2` e (`and`), ao mesmo tempo, `y1` for diferente de `y2`. Se apenas uma dessas expressões retornar falso, o `while` terminará. Em outras palavras, não necessariamente as duas expressões precisem retornar falso para que o `while` termine.

A solução mais simples que me vem na cabeça é criar um `while` infinito e colocar um `if` comparando a igualdade em vez da diferença:

```
while True:
    if x1 == x2 and y1 == y2:
        break
    # chamadas das suas funções
```

Dessa forma somente quando tudo for igual o `while` terminará.